# Delete data based on date from DOMO

Tags: domo

I need to delete data from a dataset. I read this post that I think would help (https://dojo.domo.com/discussion/comment/46624#Comment_46624) but Im not sure where to run this query to delete from the table.

Please let me know if these are the correct steps:

click SQL in DOMO url -> **MySQL** -> **input datasets** (add the table I want to delete rows from) -> **transform** (
add my delete from statement:

```
DELETE FROM
my_table
where `loaded_date` >= '2019-10-01' and `loaded_date`<= '2019-11-01';)
```

-> **output datasets** (just do select * from table? does it matter what I enter here?, can I just limit to 10?)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a way two ways to do this. Within my question I mentioned where to go to run a DataFlow, that would be one way to do this. But it matters what you write for the output dataset as that would be the new dataset you use.

So I did `SELECT * FROM my_table;`

The second way to do this is to delete the version history, so lets say I get my data daily to DOMO, I would go to the dataset url, and add this to the end: `?_f=dataRepair` . This just refreshed the page, but at the top there is a new button to click on called "data repair" select that and it will take you to all your versions. You can filter it by date as well and just delete.